# 'She/He is not available'

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

Is the following sentence correct? Or is there a better way to frame this sentence?

> 'She/He is not available'

Can the word 'available' be used to state the availability of a person? or is it restricted only to state the availability of things?

Comment: Hi. This seems easily answerable with a dictionary (Collins Dictionary: [available](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/available)). Also, if you ask for a better way to "frame" something, you should also include more context. What's happening in your situation? What kind of word are you looking for? You can [edit] your post to provide more details or explain why the dictionary was not helpful. See the [help/on-topic] and [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 2):

You can use available with people.

My boss is often not available, because he's not in. But there are cases, when his secretary says he's not available, while he's in. She can reach him, but she refuses to, because he's with some bigwig investors walking about the factory, and he is too big a person to be interrupted.

Comment: In this context, a synonym of _available_ is _free_, and it mostly refers to someone’s personal schedule, as in: “I won’t be available until next week.” An antonym might be _busy_.